# Formula output dependent on two conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a complex formula that I am getting stuck on.
I am writing a custom calculator for a product that we deliver with multiple variations.
What I need to work out is the number of controllers required for variable width and height values.

I have been able to get the following "IF" working on on the width value. but can't work out how to include the Height variable as well.

```
=IF(C6<8,1,IF(C6<=16,2,IF(C6>17,"!Check With TD!")))
```

I thought it would be something like this with the 'AND' function.

```
=IF((C6<8,1, IF(C6<=16,2, IF(C6>17,"! Check With TD !")))AND(IF(C7<6,1, IF(C7<=12,2, IF(C7>13,"! Check With TD !"))))
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

I'm trying to make it so when either the width or height limit is exceeded, the value of controller boxes change to either `1`, `2` or `!Check With TD!`.

If someone could work out how I can extend this formula to include a second variable box, I would be really appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you exactly want, as there is a whole cross product of possibilities:

`C6` could be `<8`, or `<=16` or (between 16 and 17 or) `>17`, and

`C7` could be `<6`, or `<=12` or (between 12 and 13 or) `>13`.

Each of the four options of for `C6` can be combined with each of the four options of `C7`, resulting in 16 possibilities; your formule seem to only look at three or six.

Anyway, I'll take a guess and let you adjust it if this is not what you wanted. Let's develop it step by step:

A. if *either one* is above the upper limit, you want it to fail:

`=IF(OR(C6>17,C7>13),"! Check With TD !","later")`

B. then we add the result '2':

`=IF(OR(C6>17,C7>13),"! Check With TD !", IF(OR(C6>=8,C7>=6),2, "later"))`

C. and finally the result '1' - no more IFs needed, as all other cases are already handled:

`=IF(OR(C6>17,C7>13),"! Check With TD !", IF(OR(C6>=8,C7>=6),2, 1))`

Now if you'd rather use AND (which I think makes it a bit more complicated logically), you could use:

`=IF(AND(C6<8,C7<6),1,IF(AND(C6<=16,C7<=12),2,"!Check With TD!"))`

which is identical in result.